# How resolve Could not find a declaration file for module '@/firebase'. '/MY-PATH/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, database, firebase, import, vuejs3

I am using firebase in a simple vue.js app and typescript.
VScode shows an error on @/firebsase in `import { db } from "@/firebase"`. I don't undestand how to fix it.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@/firebase'. '/MY-PATH/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

**index.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };
```

**vue.app**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {
  collection,
  query,
  where,
  onSnapshot,
  addDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "@/firebase";
```

Comment: Have you tried using relative path to that Firebase file instead of `@/`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj : relative path should be the one mentioned in the error message? I tried but the error persists. I aslo am perplexe regarding "implicitly has any type"...

Comment: @Dharmaraj : here are the organisation of the folders : https://postimg.cc/gr8YyVy0. I also tried ../firebase without success